# Catch a value from form1 to form2 in vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript, vb6

In VB, I create 2 forms in 1 project. In form1, I put 3 buttons with different value. In form2, I only put 1 textbox with no value.

My question is, how if I press one of the button in form1, the form2 is automatically opened and the value from the button that I press automatically added to the form2 textbox?

Comment: vb6 and vbscript and also vba and vb.net. Did you realize that they are different things?

Answer (score 2):

Add following code into your button handler. You can double click button and add the code into event handler which is automatically created:

```
    'Here we are creating actual object and passing string into it constructor method
    Dim instanceOfForm2 = new Form2("String value from Form1!") 
    instanceOfForm2.Show() ' Showing form
```

In Form2 we need to tweak our constructor to accept one parameter:

```
Public Sub New(someValue as String)
    InitializeComponents() 'This is always first row in form constructor
    TextBox1.Text = someValue 'And put that text into textbox...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 you can do all the stuff that lardymonkey has in place, but you don't have to.  The most concise way to do what you want is this.  First, make your three command buttons in Form1 into a control array.  To do this, give them all the same name (I'll use "cmdMyButtons" in my example), and set their index properties to 0, 1, and 2.  Then do this in Form1's code window:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ButtonText(2) As String

Public Sub Form_Load()
    ButtonText(0) = "First Button Text"
    ButtonText(1) = "Second Button Text"
    ButtonText(2) = "Third Button Text"
End Sub

Public Sub cmdMyButtons_Click(Index As Integer)
    With Form2
        .txtMyTextBox.Text = ButtonText(Index)
        .Show vbModal
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, I like lardymonkey's idea of showing modally, so I put it in here as well.  However, several things in his code sample aren't intrinsically necessary to do what you want, and create overhead, so I pulled them out:

1. You don't need to make a property; you can just set the text
   directly as I have here.
2. You don't need to create a form variable; you can just reference the form directly as I have here.
3. You don't have to load the form explicitly; the form gets
   automatically loaded as soon as you set the variable (by the way,
   the Show method also automatically loads the form, too--you only use
   Load when you want to have the form loaded into memory before you do
   anything to it).
4. If you close the modal form it will be
   automatically unloaded.  However, unloading a form doesn't set any
   object variables referencing it to nothing.  Therefore, frmDetail
   will not be Nothing when you check it, you will unload a form that
   isn't loaded.  While this doesn't throw an error (the statement is ignored), I wouldn't do it anyway.  So, you don't
   need any of the "make sure the form is destroyed" code.

And now, for a short lecture on the whole business of always explicitly destroying object variables:

There is a longstanding argument about whether you need to explicitly set all your local object variables to Nothing before exiting a subroutine in VB6.  I don't agree with this at all; VB takes care of this automatically when the variables go out of scope.  As far as I can see, the reason that people believe that they have to do this is that the scope finalizer doesn't collect garbage in any particular order, and sometimes two interacting COM objects need to be destroyed in a particular order due to poor coupling architecture.  In such a case, you do indeed need to clear the objects in the correct order to work around intermittent bugs, so the myth developed that VB's garbage collection is buggy and needs to be circumvented by always manually destroying object variables.

Frankly, the idea that a programmer is going to always do this and never forget is naive.  So I persist in disagreeing with it; the developers of VB6 put a lot more thought and effort into developing the scope finalizer than any programmer is going to put into circumventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific version of the software you are using we cant answer, we can answer it if you provide the correct version

In .net it's a simple as creating the form then passing the value over.

```
Friend objForm2 as New Form2
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
objForm2 = new Form2()
TextBox1.Text = value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way of doing it in VB6.  I've left the error handling up to you.

I've made the assumption that the name of the text box is txtOutput on form2.

In Form2 add the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Let OutputText(ByVal strOut As String)

    txtOutput.Text = strOut

End Property
```

In Form1 add the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    DisplayForm "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    DisplayForm "2"
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    DisplayForm "3"
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayForm(ByVal strValue As String)
'Declare the variables
Dim frmDetail As Form2

    'Create the form
    Set frmDetail = New Form2

    'Load the form and display it modal
    Load frmDetail
    frmDetail.OutputText = strValue
    frmDetail.Show vbModal, Me

    'Make sure the form is destoryed
    If Not frmDetail Is Nothing Then
        Unload frmDetail
        Set frmDetail = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Make sure you comment the code and if you need some error handling then add it.  If you need help with the VB6 functions you can find it here [MSDN VB6 Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: I have some issues with your code.  See my answer, and feel free to correct me if you feel that it is I who am in error.